# How to quickly iterate over multiple lists with different lengths

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration

I have two lists of different lengths, which are the range of the lower and upper bound that I am using to filter a nested list "lst". To save space, I just copy part of the data 10 times. I want to iterate over both the upper limit and lower limit twice and here is my attempt:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

lst = [[4.256, 3.8518], [2.2121, 1.6064], [3.9662, 3.2433], [5.1571, 5.8898], [4.4909, 3.7328], [9.38, 10.2276], [4.8912, 5.846], [4.5729, 3.5768], [6.25, 5.2267], [3.1019, 4.1603], [7.7822, 14.9629], [4.7673, 12.1189]]

lst_long = lst * 10

lower_limit = np.arange(1, 3, 0.1).tolist()
upper_limit = np.arange(9, 12, 0.1).tolist()

def create_combo(a, b):
    for sublist1 in itertools.product(a,b):
        for sublist2 in itertools.product(a,b):
            yield sublist1[0], sublist1[1], sublist2[0], sublist2[1]

for lower1, upper1, lower2, upper2 in create_combo(lower_limit, upper_limit):
    filtered_list = [sublist for sublist in lst_long if lower1<=sublist[0]<=upper1 and lower2<=sublist[1]<=upper2]
    x = [lst[0] for lst in filtered_list]
    y = [lst[1] for lst in filtered_list]
```

This code now takes over 9 sec to run on my pc. As the range expands, I am sure the increase in run time would be exponential. Therefore, I am looking for suggestions regarding how I may conduct the iteration more efficiently. Is there any special feature from any package that could speed up the process?

Thank you.

Comment: This is very slow because you are using the builtin list rather than the improved speed that numpy gives you. Consider using numpy functions rather than converting to list. This will give significant speedup.

Comment: @CDJB Hi, are you saying that I should delete the "to.list()'' ? I tried it, but the run time ended up increasing to 16sec..

Comment: You should do that, but also instead of using list comprehensions, use the numpy equivalents. Using list comprehensions on numpy arrays defeats the point of using numpy.